# checking instantly php arrays using jquery / ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to be able to check whether values exist in the php array without having to click the submit button to do those checks using jquery/ajax. 

**when users enter an abbreviation in the text field want to be able to show that the brand exists (either vw or tyta) or not (as they type in the input box) and show the results in the carnamestatus div**.
I was following a tutorial from youtube, however it queried against a mysql database. 
I was wondering if this is possible using php arrays instead of mysql? I would be grateful if you could pick any faults in the code.

**the code is as follows:**

```
<?php
$car = array()
$car["vw"] = array( "name" => "volkswagen");
$car["tyta"] = array( "name => "toyota");
?>
```

**the html code is as follows:**

```
<label for="carname">Car Code:</label> <input type="text" onblur="checkcar()" value="" id="carname" />
<div id="carnamestatus"></div>
```

**the checkcar()**

```
function checkcar(){
    var u = _("carname").value;
    if(u != ""){
        _("carname").innerHTML = 'checking ...';
        var B = new XMLHttpRequest();
        B.open("POST","check.php",true); /
        B.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        B.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(B.readyState==4 && B.status== 200) {
                _("carnamestatus").innerHTML = B.responseText;
            }
        }
        var v = "carnamecheck="+u;
        B.send(v);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)? Or you just looking for a simple check, returning true or false??

Comment: Your `checkcar()` function already work ? Do you able to send information via POST to the `check.php` page ?

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira i havent checked that. the reason is I tried to adapt the code from querying mysql to allegedly querying php arrays. I am not sure if it really works (so it is currently blank). do you suggest i put the php arrays in the check.php file?

Comment: Please check how to use (JQuery Post)[https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/] and then, you can use `$_POST` in your `check.php` file to filter your array by key (if you pass keys to filter).

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript keyboard event and then, send the value of the input into your php function.
For example:

```
$("#youInput").keyup(
    function() {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "post",
                url: "your_url.php",
                data: {params: $(this).val()},
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                }
            }
        );

    }
);
```

And in you php code, just retrieve the `params` value, `$_POST['params']`

**Explain**

When you press the keybord, your retrieve the value of the `input` ( here, it is `$(this).val()` where `this` represents #yourInput ), then you send the value via `ajax` (Here we use `post` type) with your `url` and the different params that you will send to the server side. If you post the value with `$_POST['params']` you will get the value entered in the input. And if it's success, the callback function will retrieve the data returned by your server side.

Here, we just use, [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) but you can find more about ajax [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) or [here](http://www.xul.fr/en-xml-ajax.html). Using library make it easy to work with.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: hi i am new to ajax. could you explain me what the above does exactly.